# Text showing Class that can be used by multiple other Classes

Tags: java, javafx

I have a specific class `MenuPane`, which extends `GridPane`. This Pane contains 3 other Panes, all of which also extend `GridPane`:
`StatPane`, which shows various numbers
`ButtonPane`, which contains multiple clickable buttons
`LogPane`, which displays text messages.

`MenuPane` can print messages by using LogPanes `push(String message)` function. However, I need to print messages as well when a `ButtonPane` Button is clicked.

What is the most efficient way to this? I could give ButtonPane the MenuPane of course, and do `this.MenuPane.LogPane.push("This is a message.");` but this looks terrible. Does anyone know a more efficient / cleaner way to do this?

LogPane code:

```
import Project.Other.Constants;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

/**
 * Created on 15/12/2017.
 * Scrollable window which contains Text messages.
 */
class LogPane extends GridPane{

  private TextArea log;

  LogPane(){
    initialize();
  }

  private void initialize(){
    log = new TextArea();
    log.setEditable(false);
    log.prefWidth(Constants.width / 3);
    log.prefHeight(Constants.height);
    log.setText("Text Log loaded. Messages:");
    setConstraints(log, 0, 0);
    getChildren().add(log);

    setMinHeight(Constants.height);
    setMaxHeight(Constants.height);
    setMinWidth(Constants.width / 3);
    setMaxWidth(Constants.width / 3);
  }

  void push(String message){
    log.setText(log.getText() + "\n" + message);
    log.appendText("");
    //log.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `messageHandler` property in your `ButtonPane`; something that handles a message simply has to "do something with a `String`", so it doesn't need to be specific to the `LogPane`, it can just be a [`Consumer<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html):

```
public class ButtonPane {

    private Consumer<String> messageHandler = s -> { } ;

    public void setMessageHandler(Consumer<String> messageHandler) {
        this.messageHandler = messageHandler ;
    }

    // ...

    // to handle a message, just do:
    // String message =  ... ;
    // messageHandler.accept(message);

}
```

Now, since your `MenuPane` already has references to the `LogPane` and `ButtonPane`, all you need is:

```
public class MenuPane {

    public MenuPane() {

        LogPane logPane = new LogPane();
        ButtonPane buttonPane = new ButtonPane();

        buttonPane.setMessageHandler(logPane::push);

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a message queue. Then have the log pane poll the message queue class for new messages to show. This would mean that all the panes would have to do something like:

```
MessageQueue.postMessage("message to display");
```

Then in your log viewer have a Timer which calls something like :

```
String messageToDisplay = MessageQueue.getMessage();
```

the class could look something like this :

```
public class MessageQueue {

     public static Queue<String> messages = new PriorityQueue<String>();

    public static void postMessage(String message)
    {
        messages.add(message);
    }

    public static String getMessage(){

        return messages.poll();

    }

}
```

I think something like that should work well for your usage.